# Need help constructing an Excel formula to calculate staff movements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the current volume of staff, as at today.
I have the volume of staff expected to start in the coming months.
I have the volume of staff expected to leave in the coming months.
I also have to group staff into stages, according to how long they have been at the company and show how many staff we have, per stage, over the coming months.
There are 4 stages:
Stage 1 : new starters will be in this stage for 3 months
Stage 2 : next, staff will be in this stage for 6 months
Stage 3 : next, staff will be in this stage for 6 months
Stage 4 : finally, they will end up in this stage and stay here until they leave

For example:
If I have 1 new starter in Jan 2024 then the flow through would look like this:

| Month | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3 | Stage 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-24 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Feb-24 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Mar-24 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Apr-24 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| May-24 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Jun-24 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Jul-24 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Aug-24 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Sep-24 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Oct-24 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Nov-24 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Dec-24 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Jan-25 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Feb-25 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Mar-25 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Apr-25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| May-25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I would then need to add the new starter to the existing volumes of staff, per stage.
For example:

| Month | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3 | Stage 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Starting Volumes | 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Jan-24 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Feb-24 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Mar-24 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Apr-24 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| May-24 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| Jun-24 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| Jul-24 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 1 |
| Aug-24 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 1 |
| Sep-24 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 1 |
| Oct-24 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 1 |
| Nov-24 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 1 |
| Dec-24 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 1 |
| Jan-25 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2 |
| Feb-25 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2 |
| Mar-25 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2 |
| Apr-25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| May-25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 |

All of the above I can achieve at the moment, but the minute I try to introduce leaver volumes into the equation, I get a bit stuck.  The data isn't based on actual people, so I can't use rows of people and dates to calculate the volumes.  The data is just numbers.  So when I have a leaver, who is in Stage 2 in August 2024, then I need to reduce down the staff volume in August 2024 and any future months that volume may have been counted, and also reduce down the staff in any future Stages that volume may have been counted in.

Here is the base data - what formula would I need to write to calculate the correct volumes of staff per month, per stage?

Existing Staff

| Month | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3 | Stage 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Starting Volumes | 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

New Staff

| Month | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3 | Stage 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-24 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Feb-24 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Mar-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Apr-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| May-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jun-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jul-24 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Aug-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Leavers

| Month | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3 | Stage 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Feb-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Mar-24 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Apr-24 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| May-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jun-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jul-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Aug-24 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Sep-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Oct-24 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Nov-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Dec-24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jan-25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: So `New staff` only logs the moment a person starts? Same with `Leavers`? Than how would you know if the leaver was somebody that started January versus February, or a different year? You would be able to calculate the number of employees only, not their current stage, in case there was a leaver.

Comment: This is my exact predicament.  The purpose of this excel spreadsheet is to allow managers to come up with "what if" situations and see how that affects the departments productivity. So the managers will look ahead and estimate that x amount of staff will leave in March 24 and will be Stage 2 when they leave.  Therefore, losing that volume of staff will affect that months productivity, but also future months productivity because that reduces down the future volumes of staff that would have been in Stage 3 and Stage 4.

Comment: Would it be possible to have an additional sheet with the list of managers with join/[leave] date? Would make it considerably easier.